# Retornar tamanho do HD e espaço livre para cliente-servidor

Tags: python, socket

Gostaria de retornar ao cliente a informação do tamanho do HD além do espaço disponível.

Código cliente

```
import socket, pickle
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9991
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
dest = (HOST, PORT)
msg = input('Entre com a mensagem:\n')
udp.sendto(msg.encode('ascii'), dest)
lista = pickle.loads(dest)
print(lista)
udp.close()
```

Código servidor

```
import socket, psutil, pickle
HOST = 'localhost'
PORT = 9991
udp = socket.socket(socket.AF.INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
org = (HOST, PORT)
udp.bind(org)
print('Esperando receber na porta: ', PORT,'...')
(msg, cliente) = udp.recvfrom(1024)
if msg.decode('ascii') == 'disponivel':
    total = round(psutil.disk_usage('/').total/(1024*1024*1024),1))
    totalDisp = round(psutil.disk_usage('/').free/(1024*1024*1024),1))
    resposta = print('Memoria total e: ', total, 'e a disponivel: ', totalDisp)
    tup_resp = pickle.dumps(resposta)
    msg.send(tup_resp)
else:
    print('Argumento invalido')
udp.close()
```

Me aparece a mensagem `a byte-type object is required, not 'tuple'`

Comment: Cara, seus códigos estão todos inline, sendo impossível analisar qualquer coisa. Poderia [edit] a pergunta e corrigir isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem um problema aqui:

```
lista = pickle.loads(dest)
```

`dest` é uma tupla, então não tem como você decodificar usando `pickle`. Imagino que você queira receber dados do socket usando `recv` ou `recvfrom` primeiro, pra depois decodificar.

Outro erro:

```
resposta = print('Memoria total e: ', total, 'e a disponivel: ', totalDisp)
```

A função print não retorna nada, então essa linha está colocando `None` em `resposta`. Tenta assim:

```
resposta = 'Memoria total e: {} e a disponivel: {}'.format(total, totalDisp)
print(resposta)
```

Se continuar dando problema, edita a pergunta coloca o erro completo inclusive com o traceback.

NOTA:
Gostaria de sugerir que não usasse sockets puros e `pickle` para transmitir dados dessa forma. Existem muitas opções, mas essa escolha de ferramentas tem grande chance de trazer problemas e dificuldades no futuro. Ao invés de `pickle` use um formato bem definido e com compatibilidade futura, como `json` ou `xml`. Ao invés de usar sockets puros, use um framework assíncrono como `trio`, além do código ficar mais claro e legível, vai facilitar coisas que você pode precisar no futuro, como cancelamento e paralelismo.

Comment: Fiz a troca para `udp.recvfrom(msg.encode('ascii'), dest)` e agora obtive a informação `TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`. Além de é claro fazer a modificação do código do servidor.

Comment: mas de acordo com a [documentação aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recvfrom) , `recvfrom` recebe um número inteiro como parâmetro! De onde você tirou a idéia de passar a mensagem como parâmetro? Você tem que olhar as funções como funcionam, que parâmetros recebem e o que vão retornar, antes de usá-las, não é só sair colocando tudo no código e esperar que funcione